# How to add a function that adds two intergers to my Collatz code

Tags: python, collatz

I want to add a function onto this already mad collatz function code that gives me two intergers, the first intergers gives the length of Collatz sequence and the other is the sequence that  has the largest length.
EXAMPLE, the function returns numbers
20 and 9
Which means that among the numbers 1, 2, 3,…, 10, nine has the
longest Collatz sequence, and its length is equal to 20.

i am thinking i need to create another function that accepts intergers and passes through a loop onto the collatz or something like so.  Here is a picture of my already made

[image: collatz code]

Just not sure how to start the process as i am quite new, thanks

EDIT-

```
n = []
def collatzSequence(n):
    print(n)
    if n==1:
        return n
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = ((n*3) + 1) // 2
    return collatzSequence(n)
print(collatzSequence(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes on your code:

- you don't create a Collatz sequence, you just `print` it, but in the end your function will always return `1` (or raise an error, see below). That `n=[]` line seems to suggest you thought to work on a `list`, but you're just working with single numbers instead
- the usual way of showing a Collatz sequence is listing each passage, as in `3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1`, while you are skipping (most) even numbers
- i wouldn't recommend a recursive solution here. Although Python's recursion depth limit is usually set to 1000, if you try some large numbers you will exceed that limit and get an error

So let's build a sequence:

```py
def collatzSequence(n):
    l=[]
    while n > 1:
        l.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = n*3 + 1
    l.append(1)
    return l
```

Now we can write a second function to find the longest sequence. It will accept a `list` or any *iterable* which yelds `int`s, perhaps a `range` object:

```py
def longestCollatz(numbers):
    maxlen = 0
    longest = None
    for num in numbers:
        newlen = len(collatzSequence(num))
        if newlen > maxlen:
            longest = num
            maxlen = newlen
    return (longest,maxlen)

longestCollatz(range(1,13,2))
(9, 20)
```